# Subcomponents rendered from state are not subscribed to props changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a generic component like the following:

```
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element[]
}

const ScreenNavigationManager = forwardRef<ScreenNavigationFunctions, Props>(
  (props: Props, ref) => {
    
    const [carousel, setCarousel] = useState<
      [JSX.Element?, JSX.Element?, JSX.Element?]
    >([])

    useEffect(() => {
      setCarousel([undefined, props.children[0], props.children[1]])
    }, [])

// ...
```

I display the carousel items in this component. They come from the parent element like so:

```
<ScreenNavigationManager ref={navigatorRef}>
  <View1 propThatChanges={randomStringThatChanges}/>
  <View2 />
  <View3 />
  {/* etc */}
</ScreenNavigationManager>
```

It all works fine, but when the `carousel` array's props change in the parent component, they do not get updated in my `<ScreenNavigationManager>` component, even though it *looks* like it should. Why isn't it?

Comment: Why you need the children in state at all? Why not just directly render them with `render ( <> { props.children } </> )`

Comment: Because I only want to render at most 3 at a time. It's a very complicated component, I'm afraid I will have to refactor the whole thing

Comment: You are right @nita, rendering the children directly works